# What do I need to switch from iOS 7 Beta to the live version?

Tags: ios, ios7

I recall when I installed the beta version of iOS 7 that there was a disclaimer saying that once the live version of iOS 7 was released to the public, we would need to perform some action to be able to receive the latest updates. Unfortunately I don't remember what that action was. Anybody have any ideas what needs to be done?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: The latest stable build is iOS 7.0.2 - 11A501. (released on Sep 26,2013)

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. If you need to update to the latest stable build then do the following.

You can install the latest iOS version in 2 ways.

1. Download the latest version of iTunes and connect your iPhone. iTunes will prompt you to update the iOS to latest version.
2. If you are a developer download the latest iOS version 7.0(11A465) for your device from [Apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and connect your iPhone to iTunes. Then click `ALT+Restore`. It will prompt you to show the location of the iOS DMG you just downloaded. Point to it and you should have the latest version installed.

If you are already on the latest build (11A465) [go to Settings->General->About->Version to check] then you should receive updates automatically.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. 1st, the latest build is 11A501. However that doesn't matter. I'm trying to revert back to the public release version of iOS7. As such I go to itunes and click "restore iphone" but it fails for me.

Comment: @NickONeill can you be specific with the version numbers? What do you mean by the public release version of iOS 7 and what is the version of iOS you are currently on? Also, let us know what is the error you get when trying to restore from iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a restore from within iTunes, there wasn't an OTA update published.

Answer (score 0):

I tried simply restoring with iTunes, but the same beta version remained on my iPhone. I had to download the public release from developer.apple.com, and then restore using that build with iTunes. I then had the new wallpapers and ringtones, which ensured that it was the public release.

Comment: Where did you find the public release?

Comment: developer.apple.com > 'Member Center' @ top > 'iOS' Dev Center > Scroll down to the iOS builds a click the one you want.

Comment: those builds are not the public ones